# Determine a prime number function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, loops

Could anyone explain to me the 2nd and 3rd statement in the for loop

What is the 1st and 2nd i in the middle part and the last one `(i = i + 6)`

```js
function prime(n) {
  if (n <= 1) return false;
  if (n <= 3) return true;

  if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false
  for (let i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) {
    if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)

      return false;
  }
  return true
}

console.log(prime(11))
console.log(prime(25))
console.log(prime(29))
```

Comment: This function simply doesn't work as prime check for primes 29 or more.  `n%1==0` is a bug, looks like. And also I couldn't get what part confuses you.

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator (remainder of division). `n % x` is zero if x is a factor of n. `n % 1 == 0` is nonsense (because that is true for any natural number), but `n % (i+2)` tests if `i + 2` is a factor of n. Anyway, this function is broken, it doesn't work. It tries to only do necessary tests, however it determines that 25 is a prime and everything greater than 25 isn't.

Comment: I have changed the statement inside `if`, from `n % 1 == 0` to `n % i == 0`, which now makes sense and this code is correct, and will determine prime numbers.

Comment: This is Trial Division with a wheel of 6.  It works but it's not very fast.

Comment: @RBarryYoung This is one of the fastest sure-shot ways to determine primality of a number, with complexity being `O(sqrt(n))`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of hacks in this function to determine primality of a number `n`.

1. Every non-prime number has at-least 1 factor less than or equal to its square root.
2. Every 6th number from 3 onwards is a multiple of 3. So, if we have already checked that 3 does not divide `n`, we can safely say numbers like 9,15,21... will not divide `n`.

The `if` inside the loop checks for divisibility of `n` by `i` or `i + 2`. Since we know, `3 | i+4` (-- from 2 above), we don't check divisibility there as it is not required. And since this loop runs from `i = 5` upto `i = sqrt(n)`, if we find no factors, we can exit the loop and return `true` for number's primality (-- from 1 above)